# Is this a coincidence or a rigorous solution

Tags: combinatorics

Question:

There are $n$ couples invited to a party, each person shakes hand with everyone except his or her spouse. Find the total number of handshakes.

Solution 1.

There are $(2n,2)$ ways to choose two people among $2n$ including $n$ couples so the total number of handshakes is $C(2n,2)-n=2n(n-1)$.

Solution 2

Each person shakes hand with $2n-2$ and the total number of couples is $n$. So the number of handshakes is $(2n-2)(n)$

While I understand the first solution, I don't get the second solution.Is this a coincidence that the two answers match, or a rigorous solution. Would the second solution work in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second solution abuses some cancellation in a way that wouldn't work in general (say, if we said $n$ families of four go to a holiday party, everyone shakes hands with everyone outside their family). The idea of the second solution is that we can count how many handshakes each person has: $2n-2$, and then multiply by the number of people $2n$, but then we've counted each handshake twice so we divide by $2$. We then conveniently observe that the $2$ in $2n$ get's cancelled.

$$ \text{# of handshakes} = \frac{1}{2} (2n)(2n-2) = n(2n-2) $$